# How to generate JSON programmatically using JSON framework for iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am creating an application in that I need to send a JSON to the server to get some response.

How to generate JSON using [JSON Framework](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-framework/) for iPhone?

What are the other possible ways?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create an array or dictionary of objects representing the information you want to send via JSON. Having done that, send `-JSONRepresentation` to the array/dictionary. That method returns a JSON string, and you send it to the server.

For instance:

```
NSDictionary *o1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"some value", @"key1",
    @"another value", @"key2",
    nil];

NSDictionary *o2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"yet another value", @"key1",
    @"some other value", @"key2",
    nil];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:o1, o2, nil];

NSString *jsonString = [array JSONRepresentation];

// send jsonString to the server
```

After executing the code above, `jsonString` contains:

```
[
    {
        "key1": "some value",
        "key2": "another value"
    },
    {
        "key1": "yet another value",
        "key2": "some other value"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an NSMutableDictionary or NSMutableArray and populate it with NSNumbers and NSStrings. Call `[<myObject> JSONRepresentation]` to return a JSON string.

eg:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:@"Sam" forKey:@"name"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:50000] forKey:@"reputation"];
NSString *jsonString = [dict JSONRepresentation];
```